# lua table sorting data

Tags: sorting, lua

I have a table that is generated by lua code and returned as a callback to client side, but the data is not ordered and I want to return a list sorted by id

```
    local players = {}
    for k, player in ipairs(QBCore.Functions.GetPlayers()) do
        local charinfo = QBCore.Functions.GetPlayer(player).PlayerData.charinfo
        local csn = QBCore.Functions.GetPlayer(player).PlayerData.citizenid
        local playerjob = QBCore.Functions.GetPlayer(player).PlayerData.job.label
        local ped = GetPlayerPed(player)
        local playerCoords = GetEntityCoords(ped)
        
        players[k] = {
            ["id"] = player,
            ["name"] = tostring(GetPlayerName(player)),
            ["charName"] = ("%s %s"):format(charinfo.firstname, charinfo.lastname),
            ["csn"] = csn,
            ["playerjob"] = playerjob,
            ["serverid"] = player,
            ["ped"] = GetPlayerPed(player),
            ["coords"] = playerCoords,
        }
    end
    cb(players)
```

Comment: a hash table has no order, you need to create a separate structure containing the keys to define the order you want to retrieve the item in.

Comment: @Nifim - OP creates an array, not dictionary.

Comment: Ah I understand the question now, thank you @EgorSkriptunoff

Answer (score 2):

you can use [table.sort](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#pdf-table.sort) to order your `players` table. this will sort the table **in-place** using the function you provide to determine the order.

`table.sort` is also explained in [Programming in Lua: 19.3 – Sort](https://www.lua.org/pil/19.3.html)

Here is an example based on your question:

```
players =
{
    {id = 3217},
    {id = 6716},
    {id = 3432},
    {id = 5575},
    {id = 6124},
    {id = 1156},
    {id = 1789},
}

table.sort(players, function(p1,p2) return p1.id < p2.id end)

for k, v in ipairs(players) do
  print(k, v.id)
end
```

Output:

```
1   1156
2   1789
3   3217
4   3432
5   5575
6   6124
7   6716
```

Comment: Thanks alot it works perfectly, how stupid I was xD I was trying to apply the solution in server side so the callback goes ordered but now I applied it on client side and it worked